# SQL Comparing Information in Tables

Tags: sql, compare, temp

I want to know how I would compare two pieces of information such as say I have two columns in my query: `surname` and `forename`. How could I check to see whether the `forename` exists in the `surname` column and visa versa?

So far I've created two temporary tables, one which selects just the `surname`, and one which selects all the other information. I was going to compare them by doing a join but im having no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Select u1.Surname, u1.Forename,
    (select count(0) from users u2 where u1.surname = u2.forename) as CountWhereForenameEqualsMySurname,
     (select count(0) from users u2 where u1.forename = u2.surname ) as CountWhereSurnameEqualsMyForename
    From users u1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your tables it is a little difficult to write a query. But I would do something like this; join the table to itself based on the `surname` being equal to the `forename`.

```
SELECT
    t1.forename as foreName1,
    t1.surname as surName1,
    t2.forename as foreName2,
    t2.surname as surName2
FROM
    tableName as t1 INNER JOIN tablename as t2
        ON
            t1.surname = t2.forename
```